# WIFI over wires

Tags: signal, signal-processing, wifi, transmission

So, guys I have made [wifi gun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk-nj_BwoBE) a but it seems not working as there are a lot of trees between my friend's wifi and my home ( 1km distance ), So is there a method to convert wifi to wire and transmit over here, So I was thinking about connecting a wire to my wifi antenna and dragging that to his house.

Any suggestions or advice?

Comment: Yes. It's called "Ethernet".

Comment: Hahaha next thing you'll be wanting phones that work over wires too.

Comment: LOL,ethernet wires are expensive bro

Comment: There's a reason why that YouTube video has gotten so many negative votes.

Comment: The question is not dumb, as wifi modulation is efficient and a cable would offer a almost error free transmission. But what advantage you expect from wifi over cable from just ethernet? PS: If I was you, I would consider buying ethernet to glasfiber converters and get 1km of glasfiber... remember, Ethernet is only good for 100m at best

Comment: What in the name of little green boogers makes people think that videos are a good way to distribute technical information?  To build a copy, you need detailed plans (**drawings**,) written descriptions of how to make and assemble the parts, and a list of troubleshooting steps for when something goes wrong (and something **always** goes wrong.)  Videos offer none of those things.

Comment: Guys,I am broke due to my age...U know what I am talkin about..Now give me a circuit and I am on my way to the electronics store.LOL

Comment: I wondered why the video link was shown in my browser as *visited*. [Related](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/510928)

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a "gimme the circuitz" site. You've asked on an electronics engineering site for questions and answers on technical design so you can expect to have to have some knowledge on the subject to phrase a decent technical question.

Comment: Can we not close this unhelpfully for just a minute while I write an answer about ethernet-over-cheaper wiring

Comment: @Transistor i was just chillin bro,u got some advice like some booster or shit,will 1km long wifi anteena work?

Comment: @ElementX What is a 1 km long wifi antenna?

Comment: LOL,so if start a wire from my antenna and hook up that to my friends antenna,will it work

Comment: You don't *want* a circuit. You want to buy some proper equipment that does this... should cost like $200 or less (rough guess). You're broke, I guess that's tough, mow some lawns and then buy it. Or ask your parents for money. Or learn about antenna design and try to make a better one.

Comment: (Also I hope your friend is next door to you on a farm or something, because people are going to get angry if you put wires through their back yards. Did you think about where to put the wires? If you can't use wires then the only option left is: learn about antenna design and try to make a better one. "Focused" wi-fi *is* possible.)

Comment: These people are all my freinds,I love my neigbourhood

Comment: The solution to this question is a point-to-point link (eg: two Ubiquiti Nanobeams, or similar product). About $200 USD in parts.

Answer (score 2):

This has got off to a bad start, but the answers are really almost there: WiFi and Ethernet are closely related through both the technology and the IEEE standards body that defines them.

The absolute simplest wifi-wire-to-wifi would be unscrewing both antennas on the APs and putting a length of coaxial cable between them. For short links this would probably need an attenuator, but a 1km piece of cable should attenuate quite effectively itself (-30dB maybe?). I'm not sure if the latency would prevent this from working effectively but I don't immediately see why it would.

[Someone claims to have actually done this.](https://hackaday.com/2018/10/19/wired-wireless-over-coax/) In their case they already had the cable installed and needed to build adapters.

The "correct" solution is ethernet-over-coax or ethernet-over-fiber, but both of those require specialised conversion equipment.

You *might* be able to make "twinax" (twin coaxial, used for satellite TV dishes) work instead of ethernet cable with appropriate baluns, but this seems like a lot of hassle and I wouldn't try it unless the link was already there.

What will almost certainly *not* work is a long piece of unshielded cable, like bell wire, speaker wire, or household mains cable. You can do Ethernet over junk for short distances but not long ones.

Comment: from my experience, only -30dB of attenuation over 1km would be an exceptional good cable... I doubt its more. Cat 5e allows just some ~25db insertion loss for 100MHz. And this is roughly what Cat5e twisted pair offers - for 100m. (of course 6,7,8 are a bit better, but not in magnitutes)

Comment: I was thinking of maybe,stepping down the frequency of the wave and transmit it over cables and do the other stuff at the other end,.....I don't have enough experience to tell wether it will work @Transistor that is why I posted here,take this technical shit,LOL

Comment: Yes, it'd have to be really low-loss. LMR-1700 (lowest loss standard product that Times Microwave sells, a very large 1.7 inch diameter coaxial cable) does about 5.7 dB/100 m @ 2.5 GHz, or about 57 dB at 1 km. Something more sane like LMR-400 (Times version of RG-8) is 22 dB / 100 m. There's a reason that DOCSIS cable internet stays mostly below 1 GHz, the attenuation is much more friendly there.

Comment: Guys if i am going to buy coax,It would take me more time than downloading Forza horion 4 via GSM

Comment: @Peter, and the prices! Virtual Air heliax coax for this kind of length and frequency will cost $500-$1000. Better to go with RG58 and a DSL modem. This is a great "youtube" idea, if the OP can add some fire & explosions, a few sprints through the forest, a social experiment, and some drone aerial shots. Extra points for a Call-Of-Duty theme.